# Define the Time Complexity for the algorithm (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following snippet of code:

```
public static int digPow(int n, int p) {
  int powCounter = p;
  int sum = 0;
  char[] digits = (""+n).toCharArray();

  for (char digit : digits) {
    sum += Math.pow(Character.getNumericValue(digit), powCounter);
    powCounter++;
  }

  if (sum % n == 0) return sum / n;
  else return -1;
}
```

I don't understand how to define the time complexity, because, even though I have a loop, it seems to me that it's not just O(n). Or it is?

Comment: _it seems to me that it's not just O(n)_ why do you think so?

Comment: It's O(log n), assuming Math.pow runs in O(1) time. I'd look carefully at your accuracy though -- you return a long (suggesting the result might not fit in an int), but `sum` is an `int`, and Math.pow takes doubles (which represent all `int` values exactly, but not all `long` values).

Answer (score 1):

Its O(n), where n is the length of the character array digits.
Since the loop will iterate that no of times the next line is a if else clause which will execute only once.

Comment: Ambiguous though, since a variable *n* is already present in the code with a different value.